# looking for a jquery ajax framework

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to integrate continous sound which continuously plays over a html website. i am looking for a jquery plugin which gives me a similar functionality as jquery mobile. it has to give me the ability to replace a part of the dom using a ajax call. additionally it should execute javascript which is fetched via ajax.

i would expect that there already is a plugin that handles external links, forms, hash history, etc. already, which jquery mobile all does. is there one?

thanks

lukas

Comment: I might misunderstand the question, but jQuery has that ability already (replacing part of the DOM using ajax) - why do you need a plugin?

Comment: you are talking about the .load() method? yes, it does fulfill a part of my requirements. but i would expect that there already is a plugin that handles external links, forms, hash history, etc. already, which jquery mobile all does.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. flagged to remove.

Comment: Yes. It's called jQuery.

Comment: @naugtur so, do you have an answer for my comment above?

Comment: @elluca there are plugins, but in fact all you need is to bind a function that loads a href with ajax. Basic stuff. Intercept the click, run `.preventDefault`, get the href attribute and load it with ajax. About 5 lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you need and is easy to find:

http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy

Comment: thank you. i will give it a try. it seems to be quite configurable. i will see how it plays with my project.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery already has that ability.....

**HTML**

```
<div id="itemToChange">This DOM text will be changed</div>
```

**JS**

```
//Fetch new JS Code that you want to execute..lets say it contains function doStuff()
$.getScript('yourJsCode.js', function (){

    //Now update the content of div with id 'itemToChange' to contain new DOM element
    $('#itemToChange').load('newContent.php',function(response, status, xhr) {

        if (status == "error") {
            $('#itemToChange').html("Sorry but there was an error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }else{
            //Successfully loaded JS and new DOM Element..call JS Function
            doStuff();
        }
});
```

Comment: i am talking about inline javascript code which is fetched via ajax. i would expect that there already is a plugin that handles external links, forms, hash history, etc. already, which jquery mobile all does.